# Question edit timeout

Tags: discussion, feature-request, edits

It is happening many times (at least for me) that I would like to edit the question (for example for formatting) and I see the edit button is disabled. I check it in half an hour, the button is still disabled. The edit appears two hour later, while I would have done it in 2 minutes. I would propose the timeout feature for editing, so the guys who press edit and continue doing something else are not locking the question forever.

Answer (score 5):

In the two hours you are waiting for the edit button to become enabled, the question *is* edited, but the edit is waiting for the Suggested Edits review queue to finish approving/rejecting it. There is nothing we can do about this. But, the good news is that you're only a few reputation points away from [2000](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit), when you gain the privilege to review the edits *and* improve them if you want.

Comment: Thank you, this makes sense now :P, but I am still wondering if there is a possibility of locking the question "forever" when clicking on "edit" button

Comment: Why lock it? Couldn't someone improve on your edit?

Comment: @Paulie_D <2kers can't see suggestions, so it's hard to improve on them:/

Comment: Sure, but the point was the locking..not the edit.

Comment: @Paulie-D well to NOT lock it, the <2ker would need access to the suggestion, if he wants to improve it, no? Or am i misunderstanding something here and making an @$$ of myself? :p

Comment: I was thinking of the lock affecting *other* editors...but perhaps I'm misunderstanding too. :)

Comment: When you hover over the edit button it says why it is disabled and in this case the reason is "Another edit is awaiting approval for this post. Further edits cannot be submitted until the pending edit is reviewed."